# SSL Error in payment process using CURL

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I'm trying to do the payment gateway integration in php. When i'm doing test mode payment from local payment process is working fine. i have successfully redirected to my payment page.i have used CURL to post the datas to payment gateway server.

But after upload it to server i could not do the payment . I got the following Error. 
SSL connect error(35)

My code is as follows.

```
$request_url= "https://mypaymentserver.com"
$url = $request_url;
$successurl = url::site('payment/textpartnerssuccess', 'http');               
$processurl = url::site('payment/textpartnersprocess', 'http');
$failurl = url::site('payment/textpartnersfail', 'http'); 

//Data bind
$invoiceno = commonfunction::randomkey_generator();
$postData = array(
    "url_succesfull" => $successurl,
    "url_process" => $processurl,
    "url_cancel" => $failurl,
    "item_id" => $jobid,
    "name" => $jobdetails[0]['job_title'],
    "currency" => $this->textpartners_currencycode,
    "price" => $amount,
    "token" => $invoiceno,
    "seller_op_id" => time(),
    "shipping_cost" => 0
);

$data = http_build_query($postData, NULL, '&');

// Create a new curl instance
$curl = curl_init();

// Set curl options
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
    CURLOPT_POST           => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $data,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
));

if (($response = curl_exec($curl)) === FALSE)
{
    // Get the error code and message
    $code  = curl_errno($curl);
    $error = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);// Close curl

    echo $error_msg = 'Payment API request for  failed: '.$error.'(' .$code.')';    exit;   
    Message::error($error_msg);

    // Parse the response
parse_str($response, $data);
}

curl_close($curl); // Close curl

// Parse the response
parse_str($response, $data);
```

Can any one help me? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Guys . Finally i have got the solution by adding the following line in curl.

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'rsa_rc4_128_sha' );

Answer (score 0):

> But after upload it to server i could not do the payment

Error 35 is reported when the client is unable to connect to the SSL server (as a result of a timeout or a protocol error). Check if the server can resolve the name, make an outgoing connection to the named host, and make an outgoing connection across port 443.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..When i'm trying to access directly from the url i can able to see the payment page. For ex, if my payment request url is like https://mypaymentserver.com/?data=... when i copy this url and paste it in my browser , i can able to see my payment page.

Comment: Also the same code is working perfectly in my local. i was successfully redirected to my payment server. but the problem is in my demo server